# how to display only those users who in the user table in the rank column have a value of 1?

Tags: php, laravel

***view***

```
@foreach($user as $u)
<tr>
    <th>{{$loop->index+1}}</th>
    {{--                    <th>{{$u->id}}</th>--}}
    <th>{{$u->name}}</th>
    <th>{{$u->surname}}</th>
    <th>{{$u->patronymic}}</th>
    <th> <a class="btn btn-primary"  style="margin-bottom: 40px"  href="{{ URL::to('user/'.$u->id) }}"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></a> </th>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

***Controller***

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::all();
    return view('admin.pages.index', compact('user'));
}
```

> it is necessary that only those users who in the users table in the
>   rank column have a value of 1 are displayed and the rest are not
>   displayed

Comment: add a where condition to your query to filter the users

Comment: and the filtration condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a [where clause](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models) to filter for Users with the correct rank.

In your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::where('rank', 1)->get();
    return view('admin.pages.index', compact('users'));
}
```

From the Laravel Docs:

> The Eloquent `all` method will return all of the results in the model's
>   table. Since each Eloquent model serves as a query builder, you may
>   also add constraints to queries, and then use the `get` method to
>   retrieve the results:

Comment: 2 minutes and note